# CSS Ordered List issue

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I want to create a ordered list that looks like

```
1.0
   1.1
      1.11
```

Currently I get

```
1
    1.1
        1.1.0.11
```

```css
/* First, set all numbered lists to use counter-reset */
OL { counter-reset: item }

/* Display all list items in a numbered list in block display */
LI { display: block }

/* Use a counter that checks the number of items and adds a "." between them and ends with ". " */
LI:before { content: counters(item, ".") " "; counter-increment: item }

/*  */  
ol ol ol {counter-reset: item 10; }
ol ol ol:nth-child(1) {counter-reset: item 10;}
```

```html
<ol>
    <li>Test Level 1</li>
    <ol>
        <li>Test Level 2</li>
        <ol>
            <li>Test Level 3</li>
          <li>Test Level 4</li>
            <li>&nbsp;</li>
        </ol>
    </ol>
</ol>
```